# Amending Average Calculator - Python

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop, sum, average

I'm trying to amend an exam average calculator that I built to calculate overall average after ending the while loop, (example desired output below the code). I have functioning code that currently calculates averages for individual students, but I haven't been able to find a way to calculate an overall average. The current code errors out saying: TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable

```
numExams = int(input("How many exam grades does each student have? "))
students = 0 
total = 0
moreGrades = "Y" 

while moreGrades == "Y" :
    print("Enter the exam grades: ")
    total = 0 
        for i in range(1, numExams + 1) :
            score = int(input("Exam %d: " % i))
            total = total + score

    average = total / numExams
    print("The average is %.2f" % average)

moreGrades = input("Enter exam grades for another student? (Y/N)")
moreGrades = moreGrades.upper()
students = students + 1
total = sum(average)
print("The overall average is: ", total/students)
```

Example Desired output:

```
How many exam grades does each student have? (2)
Enter the exam grades.

Exam 1: (40)
Exam 2: (40)
The average is 40.00

Enter exam grades for another student? (Y/N) Y
Enter the exam grades

Exam 1: 20
Exam 2: 60
The average is 40.00

Enter exam grades for another student? (Y/N) n
The overall average is 40.00
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.
Your indentation is invalid, and I'm not sure where you *think* the bottom of the loop should be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to sum up a float number, which is not possible:

```
>>> sum(40.00)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    sum(40.00)
TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable
```

Your code also have some indentation errors, here's a working version of your code:

```
numExams = int(input("How many exam grades does each student have? "))
students = 0 
total = 0
moreGrades = "Y"
average = [] # set average to an empty list

while moreGrades == "Y" :
    print("Enter the exam grades: ")
    total = 0 
    for i in range(1, numExams + 1) : # you have indentation error here
        score = int(input("Exam %d: " % i))
        total = total + score

    average.append(total / numExams)
    print("The average is %.2f" % average[-1])

    moreGrades = input("Enter exam grades for another student? (Y/N)")
    moreGrades = moreGrades.upper()
    students = students + 1
total = sum(average)
print("The overall average is: ", total/students)
```

Code output:

```
How many exam grades does each student have? 2
Enter the exam grades: 
Exam 1: 40
Exam 2: 40
The average is 40.00
Enter exam grades for another student? (Y/N)Y
Enter the exam grades: 
Exam 1: 20
Exam 2: 60
The average is 40.00
Enter exam grades for another student? (Y/N)N
The overall average is:  40.0
```

Comment: I didn't indent properly pasting to it to here, so I knew about the indentation errors, but the list is all I needed! I should've thought to use one, but I'm a beginner, so it slipped my mind.

Answer (score 1):

It's because you are trying

```
total = sum(average)
```

You can define `average` outside the `while` loop as

```
average = []
```

So it's a list and you can append each average inside your `while` loop to this. Refer the documentation for [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum).